# SQL: Using function in WHERE clause to convert date to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, reporting-services, where-clause

I have several SSRS reports where the user must enter a date range, and the report needs to function whether a timestamp is included or not.

I know that when a timestamp is not included in a SQL date, it is assumed to be `'00:00:00.000'` So when searching for orders `WHERE orderDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-02'`, for example, it will not include any orders taken on 2019-01-02. I can't simply use `DATEADD(d, 1, @endDate)` or `CONVERT(date, orderDate)` because the user may have entered their own timestamp value that I would like to stay true to.

If a user enters a simple date for the end of their date range, I need to convert that to a datetime value. Since I do this so frequently, I created a function called `dbo.DateToDatetime` that passes in the date that was entered, checks if it has a timestamp, and if not adds its own timestamp value of `'23:59:59.997'`:

```
SELECT @datetime = CASE WHEN CONVERT(time, @date) = '0:0:0' THEN @date + '23:59:59.997' ELSE @date END
```

I frequently use this function in the `WHERE` clause like so:

```
WHERE orderDate BETWEEN @startDate AND dbo.DateToDatetime(@endDate)
```

I know in general using functions in `WHERE` clauses is bad practice, and I'm concerned about the effect this has on the efficiency of my queries. Is there a better solution? Would I be better off typing out the case statement every time instead of using a function?

Comment: Functions are bad in WHERE clauses when used on fields within the table, especially when used against fields in the index being used / targeted, because these cause a conversion against every row examined, and if against an index, reduce or eliminate the indexes usefulness.  The way you are using it, converting a parameter, will not significantly impact your query's operations.

Comment: Do note that, when using BETWEEN, you never get the last value in your return set. So if someone set the end time to, say, 10:15:00, knowing that a row exists with that value, they won't see that row returned.  I might change your function to `SELECT @datetime = CASE WHEN CONVERT(time, @date) = '0:0:0' THEN DATEADD(day, 1, @date) ELSE @date END`, and use `WHERE orderDate >= @startDate AND orderDate < dbo.DateToDatetime(@endDate)` instead

Comment: Just declare a new one `DECLARE @END_DATE DATETIME = dbo.DateToDatetime(@endDate)`

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use IF statement is SQL connected to SSRS parameter which flag if input is with timestamp or not then execute chosen SQL select  statement with proper format of where clause.
Also - you can compose SQL statement in SSRS expression and "inject" it to where clause via exec @sql

Answer (score -2):

you can use a cast to get proper output

```
CAST(orderDate as date) BETWEEN CAST(@startDate as date) and CAST(@endDate as date)
```